# Aspect not advising over different project

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a project that is composed out of 5-6 projects with dependencies between them.

here it is:

> ```
> @Aspect
> public class MonitoringAspect {
> Logger  logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonitoringAspect.class);
> @Around("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(value)")
> public <T> Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Monitored value) throws Throwable {
>     Object output = null;
>     Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
>     StringBuilder statistics = new StringBuilder();
>     statistics.append("\nStatistics: method [" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "] ");
>     statistics.append("arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
>     stopwatch.start();
>     output = joinPoint.proceed(); // continue on the intercepted method
>     stopwatch.stop();
>     statistics.append("Elapsed time in ms = " + stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
>     logger.debug(statistics.toString());
>     return output;
> }}
> ```

And The annotation:

> ```
> @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
> @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
> public @interface Monitored {
> String value();
> ```
>
> }

If i use the annotation @Monitored from the same project that the aspect and annotation are "physically" located, everything is working find and the method is advised, but if i try to use it on a different project (like putting them in an infra project so all projects can use it). it doesn't work for these projects (but it does for that infra project that i put the files in).

seems to me it should work, or i don't understand something

Thanks.

Comment: Your description sounds like you are describing maven projects or projects in your IDE. How does an useful variant of this project look like? It's a .war, .ear, something else?

Comment: correct, this is a maven project in eclipse, eventually its a WAR project, but all other 5-6 projects are JARS. in general they all act the same with regard to this question

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question with `spring-aop`, I assume you are using Spring framework. In such a context, `@Aspect` annotations are processed at the initialization of the `ApplicationContext`, and you should tell Spring somewhere (in a xml file, or a `Configuration` class) in what packages it should search annotations. But I must admit I never tried that myself.

Comment: How is that answer relevant if for each project alone it works perfectly? the only problem is between the projects. eventually they are all a part of the same WAR

Comment: @Gleeb That's precisely what I meant : the `ApplicationContext` should be defined only in the project that generates the war , or do you have a different build process ?